# How to get screen back on ssh server after X forwarding

Tags: 18.04, ssh, xorg, remote, x11-forwarding

I have two physical computers with Ubuntu Bionic 18.04 LTS. Let's call the one with ssh server *server*, the one with the ssh client *client*. They have each have their own physical screen. One screen is physically attached to the server. The other screen is physically attached to the client. I launch from the client on the server a graphical application, eg

```
ssh -X server totem
```

using X11-forwarding.
After I stop the application, the screen on the server is frozen, ie even the mouse does not move. In other word, the server's physical screen attached to the server physical host is frozen when the client closes the program from the client's physical screen. As far as I know, the only way for the graphic card to work again on the server is to reboot the computer. How to get the display to work again without rebooting the server?

Comment: Your problem description is unclear. Where does the application run? Where does it display? Which system's screen is "frozen", and what does "frozen" mean? Are both systems Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: I edited my post. I hope it is clear.

Comment: Still not clear to me and if I understand correctly then this is very peculiar occurrence. Are the client and server on different physical hosts? Are these screens different physical screens or different terminal windows on the same physical screen? Are both screens attached to the client physical host? It sounds as if you mean that the server's physical screen attached to the server physical host is frozen when the client closes the program from the client's physical screen? You can see how confused I am. Please tell us exactly what is the program you are running.

Comment: "It sounds as if you mean that the server's physical screen attached to the server physical host is frozen when the client closes the program from the client's physical screen?" yes, exactly. I edited my post again. An example of application can be totem.

Comment: How do you quit `totem`?

Comment: I simply close the application by closing the window

Comment: Try closing via typing `q` in the `totem ` window. Closing the window takes the code thrugh an error path ("My window has been closed!) that seems to have a bug. `q` _might_ do a better cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried x11 forwarding yet, but maybe display manager configuration somehow influences it.

If you still able to send commands through ssh when graphics is freezing, you could restart display manager:

```
sudo systemctl restart lightdm
```

You could replace lightdm by gdm3, lxdm or whatever. You could even try to switch to different display manager:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
```

and check if the issue appears again.

To check what display manager is used in your case, use the next command:

```
ps -A | grep dm
```